# C++ - Error E2285 : Could not find a match for 'tolower(char *)' in function parseInput(fstream &)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, tolower

Given the following code:

```
 void parseInput(fstream &inputFile) {
        const int LENGTH = 81;
        char line[LENGTH];

        while(!inputFile.fail()) {
            inputFile.getline(line,LENGTH);
            line = tolower(line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
```

upon compiling I'm getting this error:

> Error E2285 : Could not find a match
>   for 'tolower(char *)' in
>   function parseInput(fstream &)

I know it returns an int, but not an int[], does that mean instead of using getline i should get input character to character?  is there a way to convert the whole line to lower? Thanks in advance for everyone's help!

Comment: **Read** the error message and **think** about the code that's being complained about. The return value is obviously not the problem, because `tolower` returns an int **and you assign to an int** - who said anything about an `int*` ? The **parameter** is the problem: it says that it can't find `tolower(char*)`, because that's what you're trying to call - i.e. you're **passing** a `char*` (really a `char[]` that decays), and that version of `tolower` doesn't exist - as others noted, you want to pass a `char`. We use a loop or `std::transform` to repeat the process for each `char` in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply perform the following loop to convert a string, character-by-character, to lower case:

```
const int lineLen = strlen( line );
for ( int i = 0; i < lineLen; i++ )
{
     line[i] = static_cast< char >( ::tolower( static_cast< unsigned char >( line[i] ) ) );
}
```

*Edit:* furthermore the following code is even easier (assuming the string is null terminated).

```
_strlwr( line );
```

Comment: yeah I think i'm going to have to iterate through the character string to do this, I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: -1 for incorrect use of `tolower` (its argument must be non-negative or EOF).

Comment: Changed a program with undefined behavior into a program with ill-formed b

Comment: @Goz oh wait, i *did* post that comment? I thought i pressed on cancel :) Anyway, that should havebeen " behavior", but i removed it because "ill-formed behavior" sounds like nonsense, but I did let the "b" alone. I certainly haven't slept or 15 hours. You really can see the first effects!

Comment: @Johannes:  Fair enough ... whats the ill-formed behaviour?

Comment: @Goz: the `reinterpret_cast` you added can't perform that conversion. but, don't feel bad about that: one of the most well-known C++ experts did the same (just slightly different types) once. ;-) So, I just fixed it for you: a `static_cast` does the job. Personally I'd just a C style cast for this expressed in C++ notation. But since a C style cast is ungood in most other contexts, people might get the wrong impression from that, so, `static_cast` it is (though I used a C style cast in my own answer, I didn't think about the association effect where people might pick up Bad Habits). Cheers,

Comment: @Alf: TBH I'm surprised noone commented on that strlen earlier ;)  I woukld have done!

Comment: @Goz: i'm just a bit lacking in courage, i don't want to sound like i'm bashing. so i just pointed out the main technically incorrect thing. after all, speed is secondary concern (correctness first!), and supporting non-ASCII characters in general (using `setlocale`) third concern, or perhaps no concern at all, depending on context; e.g. I think the code as-is will work for Windows ANSI Western with non-national but non-ASCII chars like euro sign '€'. Cheers,

Answer (score 6):

Hi tolower function input parametr must be char not char*, but if you use std you can use string and std:transform to make string lower case

```
std::string data = “MyStrData”; 
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Comment: That works with a `char*` too: `std::transform(line, line + strlen(line), ::tolower);`

Comment: @ephemient Thanx ill never use transform with char* ill keep it in my mind )

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about transform, I've not used STL very much it is something I intend on learning probably during the Holidays.

Comment: @blakejc70 No problem just ask :)

Comment: Note that (a) `tolower` is in namespace `std` and should be qualified and (b) there is also a locale `std::tolower` function, so `(int(*)(int))std::tolower` may need to be used to disambiguate the function.

Comment: One can easily exploit this unsafe code by passing it a `"\x80"`. On many systems the ctype functions use lookup tables and `-128` will read out of memory of that lookup table. On my system, for example, `islower(-2222222)` crashes with SIGSEGV.

Comment: -1 for incorrect use of `tolower` (its argument must be non-negative or EOF).

Answer (score 3):

The standalone `tolower` function only accepts one `int`, and the `int` needs to be strictly nonnegative or `EOF`, otherwise behavior is undefined. Another version of `tolower` exists, which however is a template. Both of these facts make it difficult to use them with `transform` easily and safely.

C++ also provides `tolower` in its `ctype` facet, which you can use here

```
std::ctype<char> const& c = std::use_facet< std::ctype<char> >(std::locale());
c.tolower(line, line + std::strlen(line));
```

However the whole code shows you aren't familiar with arrays and points, so maybe you should start using `std::string` and easy to use algorithms? Look into `boost::string_algo`'s [case conversions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.case_conv_hpp).

Comment: +1 This answer is good in that it is apparently correct. Also ref to Boost. :-) But I think you should have discussed consequence of your first remark. Also I find the code abhorrent. Not your fault, that, I find the design of the standard library here abhorrent, resulting in unreadable gobbledegook, that takes time both to create and to decipher... So, posting my own simpler answer. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Hm, three answers here managed to use `tolower` *incorrectly*.

Its argument must be non-negative or the special `EOF` value, otherwise Undefined Behavior. If all you have are ASCII characters then the codes will all be non-negative, so in that special case, it can be used directly. But if there's any non-ASCII character, like in Norwegian "blåbærsyltetøy" (blueberry jam), then those codes are most likely negative, so casting the argument to unsigned `char` type is necessary.

Also, for this case, the C locale should be set to the relevant locale.

E.g., you can set it to the user's default locale, which is denoted by an empty string as argument to `setlocale`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>           // std::string
#include <ctype.h>          // ::tolower
#include <locale.h>         // ::setlocale
#include <stddef.h>         // ::ptrdiff_t

typedef unsigned char   UChar;
typedef ptrdiff_t       Size;
typedef Size            Index;

char toLowerCase( char c )
{
    return char( ::tolower( UChar( c ) ) );     // Cast to unsigned important.
}

std::string toLowerCase( std::string const& s )
{
    using namespace std;
    Size const      n   = s.length();
    std::string     result( n, '\0' );

    for( Index i = 0;  i < n;  ++i )
    {
        result[i] = toLowerCase( s[i] );
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );                    // Setting locale important.
    cout << toLowerCase( "SARAH CONNER LIKES BLÅBÆRSYLTETØY" ) << endl;
}
```

Example of instead doing this using `std::transform`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>        // std::transform
#include <functional>       // std::ptr_fun
#include <string>           // std::string
#include <ctype.h>          // ::tolower
#include <locale.h>         // ::setlocale
#include <stddef.h>         // ::ptrdiff_t

typedef unsigned char   UChar;

char toLowerCase( char c )
{
    return char( ::tolower( UChar( c ) ) );     // Cast to unsigned important.
}

std::string toLowerCase( std::string const& s )
{
    using namespace std;
    string          result( s.length(), '\0' );

    transform( s.begin(), s.end(), result.begin(), ptr_fun<char>( toLowerCase ) );
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );                    // Setting locale important.
    cout << toLowerCase( "SARAH CONNER LIKES BLÅBÆRSYLTETØY" ) << endl;
}
```

For an example of using the C++ level locale stuff instead of C locale, see Johannes' answer.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

yes and no.
you can get a whole line but print it char after char (and using tolower) using a for loop.

Answer (score -1):

`tolower()` only work on one character at a time.  You should do something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
  line[i] = tolower(line[i]);
```

Comment: thanks, that was what I was afraid of, no big deal easy to fix, thanks a lot!

Comment: -1 for incorrect use of tolower (its argument must be non-negative or EOF).